# Asp.Net core async action in controller

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

best practise is using async actions in API. OK:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return "END";
    }
```

I call this code multiple. There are responses time:
1. 10s
2. 20s
3. 30s
.... responses are not async but sync? Why?

Why aren't all the responses in 10 seconds when it's async?

Comment: Why is that @Alexan?

Comment: How are you invoking it? What were you expecting?

Comment: is it possible that when you invoke the requests, you are iteratively invoking them in a non-parralel fashion? I.e. in pseudo code: for(x=0;x<3;x++) { call get(); }

such an approach would guarantee you do not take advantage of the non-blocking state of async/await, since you must wait for the completion of the request in order to start the next one on the CLIENT.